# How do I change a few characters in a large text file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a large file `file.dat`, a database dump in a CSV format that looks like this:

```
file_id,line_id,st_x,st_y,value1,value2,...value100
111111,1,22.22222,33.33333,0.1234567,0.246890,0.369258,...
.....
```

It has several million lines.

Suddenly I realized that I want to change the names of the columns: 
change `st_x` to `lon` and `st_y` to `lat`.

Just copying the file on my machine takes some time, let's say `T_copy` seconds.

Editing the file with

```
sed -i 's/st_y/lat/' file.dat
```

takes `T_sed` seconds where `T_sed ~ 1.7 T_copy`.

Is there a faster method? I would not mind if the replacement string had to have the same number of characters as the target string.

**Note:** I am sure this question has been asked before, just do not see how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest viewing the file with midnight commander's viewer (F3 or mcview), then

- Press <kbd>F4</kbd> (Hex),
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd> (Edit),
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump the cursor to the text column of the viewer,
- Position the cursor to the characters you want to overwrite and type
  new values filling up the remnants of the old values with spaces,
- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> (Save)
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> (Quit)